# How do I prevent source engine based games from adding the English US keyboard layout?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I'm on Win10 and I use the german keyboard layout. Whenever I start a source engine based game, "DEU" pops up in the task bar to tell me I currently use the german layout and can now switch to ENG US if I want.

How can I prevent this? It's not only because I dont want to accidentily switch to the other keyboard. I also do not want to remove this every time again after starting the game by adding the language (as a whole, not the keyboard layout) ENG US in the system settings and then removing it to also remove the keyboard layout.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the layout?

Comment: When I remove the layout, it gets added again when I start a game.

Comment: Have a look at this bug report on steam forums: [Source based games keep adding US keyboard layout](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/SteamClientBeta/discussions/1/864976115478357063/)

Answer (score 3):

> **ATTENTION!!! The solution renames the registry keys for english USA layout!!!**
>
> **Use only if you know what you are doing!**
>
> **First backup your registry!**

Execute in PowerShell:

```powershell
Rename-Item -Path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000409" -NewName "00000409.bak" -ErrorAction Ignore;
Rename-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layout\DosKeybCodes" -Name "00000409" -NewName "00000409.bak" -ErrorAction Ignore;
Rename-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Keyboard Layout\DosKeybCodes" -Name "00000409" -NewName "00000409.bak" -ErrorAction Ignore;
```

> <s>You can switch layout using `win+space`. `alt+shift` will still use ENG USA when switching although it will not be displayed on the taskbar.</s>

After *some* Windows updates may need to re-execute commands.

> **It can be considered only a temporary solution until you find a more correct one.**

Comment: Should running these commands instantly remove the US keyboard layout from the display? "ENG US" is still listed and can be switched to.

Comment: You can switch using win + space. Alt + shift will still use ENG US when switching.

Comment: After running these commands the keyboard selection menu has disappeared entirely, the hotkey has no effect and I seem to be locked to the US layout. I\ve added and removed keyboard in  "Region & language" settings, does not solve the issue. I created a system restore point, but either the creation failed or I somehow did not finish the process.

Comment: Note that I did not restart after writing the first comment.

Comment: I was able to restore my Nordic layout by adding another English language (UK) in Windows settings and then configuring my regional keyboard, but it seems that I can't delete the newly added language, otherwise the layouts disappear again. I wonder how these commands work for the other users. I don't really mind, I shouldn't have run commands I don't understand in the first place and I should reinstall Windows in any case.

Comment: What is the problem in your particular case can not say. You can try to add the necessary languages with the following commands. `$languageList = New-WinUserLanguageList "de-DE"; $languageList.Add("ru-RU"); Set-WinUserLanguageList $languageList -Force;` "de-DE" and "ru-RU" should be replaced with the necessary.

Comment: Works now after all, the keyboard layout just isn't visible when only one is enabled. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Since MS does not want to fix the issue, I wrote a tool: https://github.com/AgentMC/KbLayoutUnloader
A compiled version is provided but feel free to compile C code yourself.