# How can one disable automatic re-adding of an unwanted keyboard layout in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

**Canonical question:** One has a Windows 10 installed with display language A, but uses keyboard layout B. What does one need to do, to stop Windows from automatically adding an unwanted keyboard layout from language A to one's system?

**My example:** I have a Windows 10 in English and I'm using a Slovenian keyboard layout. And this is working just fine, until I run a certain program that Windows ever so intelligently thinks needs an US keyboard layout. Windows adds this unwanted layout automatically, switches to it and doesn't remove it afterwards. The new layout isn't even listed in installed layouts. The only way to remove it after it appears, is to manually add it as a keyboard layout and remove it.

It seems that's a common problem for many people but after many hours of googling, I just couldn't find a good solution for it... It would be perfectly fine with me if I could just completely remove the US keyboard layout from my system, but if I do that, the keyboard stops working in some programs altogether.

Programs that I or other people have this problem with:
ICQ, some versions of Microsoft Office (lol), games based on Source engine, some versions of UltraVNC, Adobe CC Suite, and the list goes on.

[image: Unwanted keyboard layout that Windows keeps adding]

Comment: Allright Ramhound, I did it and I'm desperate. Do you think you could help me and others facing the same problem? Where's this Root Access that you mentioned?

Comment: @Brane Does your keyboard change when you press ctrl+shift or alt+shift? maybe this is accidently changing your keyboard layout from time to time.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you reply. Nope, doesn't change at all. However there's a Win+space shortcut in Windows 10 that does change the layout, but it's not the cause of this. I can press all the layout chaging combinations all I want and nothing will happen. Well, nothing will happen when I have only my kbd. layout installed. But whenever I run a certain program, this US layout gets added automagically, and after that occurs, I can use Win+space to change the layout. It's just extremely annoying having to change the layouts when I only ever want to use one single layout for everything.

Comment: @Brane I've added one more solution to my answer. For me it doesn't switch anymore after following all procedures. I've installed Win 10 on a VMware and used office to test if it switched but it didnt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent source engine based games from adding the English US keyboard layout?](https://superuser.com/questions/1132724/how-do-i-prevent-source-engine-based-games-from-adding-the-english-us-keyboard-l)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you've already tried but here are some possible solution that might help you out.

**Override default input method**

If you go to: Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Language > Advanced settings

You will see an option to override default input method. You can set this to your wanted keyboard setting.

If you click on Change language bar hot keys (see image bottom) you can change the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> hotkeys. A button in the Advanced tab will say Change key sequence. You can put them on non assigned.

[image]

**Set default input method in language options**

If you go to: Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Language

A screen like this will come up

[image: language options]

1. Select your wanted language and move it up to the top.
2. Then click on Options
3. A second screen will popup.
4. Add a different input method in your case English Slovenian keyboard
   and then delete the other one.

[image]

**Add a reg key**

You can add a **DWORD** called **IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout** with regedit to the following folder in regedit. Give it a value of **1**.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Control > Keyboard Layout
```

Or copy and paste this in a text editor and save it as .reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout"=dword:00000001
```

Then double click it and it will add the reg key for you.

**Remove the keyboard layout also in REG**

1. Go to the Region & Language settings
2. Click on Options at the only Language that is there
3. Under Keyboards delete the US layout
4. Save that setting
5. Then start regedit and go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Keyboard Layout > Preload
6. Right click on Preload and click Permissions

[image]

Deny permission for everyone but make sure 1 account is still able to change it. (just make a new account and give that access). Oterwise you lock youself out of that reg map. Now only the other user can change that reg key.

I'm still looking for more possible solutions but this is what I got for now. Let me know how it worked out for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried all that. Doesn't help. But thanks for taking a look and all the effort you put into this. I'm sure it'll be useful to many people who find it via search. A side note: the registry value `IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout` is useful for Remote Desktop servers - it forces the keyboard layout defined on the server to any users connecting to it via RDP.

Answer (score 0):

> **ATTENTION!!! The solution removes the registry keys for US layout!!!**
>
> **Use only if you know what you are doing!**
>
> **First backup your registry!**

Execute in PowerShell:

```powershell
Remove-Item -Path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layouts\00000409" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Remove-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layout\DosKeybCodes" -Name "00000409" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
Remove-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Keyboard Layout\DosKeybCodes" -Name "00000409" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
```

After *some* Windows updates may need to re-execute commands.

It can be considered only a temporary solution until you find a more correct one.