# Remove English-International from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, input-languages

I cannot find a way to remove English International localization from the computer. It is not available in Settings/Language.

Does anyone know how to do it?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g21GC.jpg)

Comment: Does [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1182822/how-can-one-disable-automatic-re-adding-of-an-unwanted-keyboard-layout-in-window) help?  [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1360623/cant-remove-unneeded-keyboard-layouts-no-such-setting-anywhere/1469157#1469157) might also help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it that easily. What you can do is change the preferred language.

If you go to the settings that you displayed in your screenshot, click on the language that you want to be the default language. Next step click on the upper arrow that appears.

If you only want to remove English(United States) - International keyboard. On the same settings screen as in the screenshot:

1. Press "English (United States)"
2. Press Options
3. Go to the bottom of the screen at "Keyboards" click on United States-International
4. Click remove

I am not sure that this is what you are looking for but hopefully it helps!